# jQuery autocomplete doesn't want to send particular POST data

Tags: python, django, jquery-autocomplete

I'm trying to add an item (fund). The autocomplete succeeds in showing all the funds. It should retrieve the `fund.id` corresponding to that 'fund'. If I could get another set of eyes on this, it would be greatly appreciated...

Just to be clear: I'm not getting a specific error. My view just redirects if there is no 'fund' in the POST. I'm just trying to figure out why my autocomplete isn't posting the fund POST value' (fund.id).

-- Thank you advance

**Template**:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="{{ STATIC_URL }}js/autocomplete/add_fund_autocomplete.js"></script>
...
<form method="POST" action="/profile/edit/">
 {% csrf_token %}
      <input type="hidden" name="fund" id="id_fund" />
      <div class="inline-block">
           <label for="id_omnibox">Fund</label>
           <input id="id_omnibox" name="omnibox" placeholder="Enter a fund name or search for an existing..." type="text" />
      </div>
      <div class="input-prepend inline-block">
           <label for="id_amount">Allocation</label>
           <span>$</span>
           <input id="id_amount" name="amount" type="text" placeholder="Enter amount" />
      </div>
      <button class="add" type="submit" name="add_position">Add</button>
 </form>
```

**add_fund_autocomplete.js**:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $.get('/autocomplete/funds/', function(data) {
        var completions = new Array();
        var dict = JSON.parse(data, function(key, value) {
            completions.push(key);
            return value;
        });
        $('#id_omnibox').autocomplete({
            source: completions,
            minLength: 2,
            select: function(event, ui) {
                $('#id_fund').val(dict[ui.item.value]);
            }
        });
    });
});
```

**(autocomplete)View**:

```
@login_required
def funds(request):
    funds = Fund.objects.exclude(name='Placeholder')
    result = {}
    for fund in funds:
        result[fund.name] = str(fund.id)
    return HttpResponse(json.dumps(result))
```

**For example:** 
*Adding the fund     `Hoth Ltd` with an amount of $`123`.
Hoth Ltd's `fund.id` should be `1`.*

**POST data**

```
POST
---------------------------------------------------------
Variable               Value
---------------------------------------------------------
fund                   u'' #empty? :\
csrfmiddlewaretoken    u'436f77eb2023043be2f5242bb0443d80'
omnibox                u'Hoth Ltd'
amount                 u'123'
add_position           u'' #Just a trigger used in my view
```

Answer (score 0):

The variable `dict` is undefined when the select callback function is called.

You can just use `ui.item.value`.

Comment: Doing `ui.item.value` isn't the trick. I have an exact autocomplete that works perfectly elsewhere. For some reason this is the only autocomplete that is giving me trouble. Maybe you've pointed me in the right direction. Thank you for you input.